# Exception Problem when using Google Documents List Data API with PHP

Tags: php, api, google-docs

I am trying to upload, download documents and spreadsheets using Google Documents List Data API with PHP. I gone through the documents and FAQ's. Only version 1.0 is available for sample using php in Google Documents List API. When i am registering my localhost domain with google domains it says not verfified even i tried with both methods ( meta tag & upload html ).

The sample php file throws the fatal error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with message 'Unable to Connect to ssl://www.google.com:443. Error #0: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. ' in C:\xampp\htdocs\google-docs\Zend\Gdata\AuthSub.php:119 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\google-docs\index.php(640): Zend_Gdata_AuthSub::getAuthSubSessionToken('CJX5oZXTFBDPuoe...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\google-docs\index.php(742): getAuthSubHttpClient() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\google-docs\index.php(935): runWWWVersion() #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\google-docs\Zend\Gdata\AuthSub.php on line 119
```

what is the cause of this error ? and how can i make it work ? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`No such host is known` means it can't resolve google.com for some reason.  This sounds like some kind of networking error, possibly DNS.  Can you ping google.com from the same machine?

Also, when you say 'register your localhost domain', do you mean you are trying to register `localhost` as a google apps domain?  I am fairly sure this will not work.  you need an actual domain name (i.e. example.com)